# How many cores do kubernetes pods use when it's CPU usage is limited by policy?

Tags: kubernetes, gunicorn, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes allows to limit pod resource usage.

```
requests:
  cpu: 100m
  memory: 128Mi
limits:
  cpu: 200m   # which is 20% of 1 core
  memory: 256Mi
```

Let's say my kubernetes node has 2 core. And I run this pod with limit of CPU: 200m on this node. In this case, will my pod use it's underlying node's **1Core's 200m** or **2Core's 100m+100m**?

This calculation is needed for my [gunicorn worker's number formula](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers), or nginx worker's number etc..
In gunicorn documentation it says

> Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers
>   to start off with.

So should I use 5 workers? (my node has 2 cores). Or it doesn't even matter since my pod has only allocated 200m cpu and I should consider my pod has 1 core?

***TLDR:*** How many cores do pods use when its cpu usage is limited by kubernetes? If I run `top` inside pod, I'm seeing 2 cores available. But I'm not sure my application is using this 2 core's 10%+10% or 1core's 20%..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will limit to 20% of one core, i.e. 200m. Also, `limit` means a pod can touch a maximum of that much CPU and no more. So pod CPU utilization will not always touch the limit.

Total CPU limit of a cluster is the total amount of cores used by all nodes present in cluster.

If you have a 2 node cluster and the first node has 2 cores and second node has 1 core, K8s CPU capacity will be 3 cores (2 core + 1 core). If you have a pod which requests 1.5 cores, then it will not be scheduled to the  second node, as that node has a capacity of only 1 core. It will instead be scheduled to first node, since it has 2 cores.

Comment: Mhm, so even tough i can see there are 2 cores available inside pod by using `top` command, that doesn't mean my app can actually use 2 core's 10%+10%. Instead it will just sit on 1 core's 20%?

Comment: yes..it will use maximum of 20% of 1 core as it limit.

Comment: The K8S documentation is a bit vague on this but it states: "A Container *might* or might not be allowed to exceed its CPU limit for extended periods of time. However, it will not be killed for excessive CPU usage." - 

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run

Comment: This answer conflicts with another chosen answer here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1065763/can-i-have-multiple-threads-running-in-parallel-in-a-pod-with-a-cpu-limit-set-to
From what I understand, even with less than 1000m, your application can use multiple cores.

Answer (score 4):

CPU is measured in units called millicores. Each node in the cluster introspects the operating system to determine the amount of CPU cores on the node and then multiples that value by 1000 to express its total capacity. For example, if a node has 2 cores, the node’s CPU capacity would be represented as 2000m. If you wanted to use a 1/10 of a single core, you would represent that as 100m.

So, if in your cluster you provided `200m` milicores, then it will stick to one core and take up the 20 percent of that core. Now if you provided another pod with `1.5m`, then only it will take up more than one core.

Comment: Mhm, i see thank you very much for explanation. So I should consider all my pods that limited under 1000m as single core, and my applications will only use single core right? So in my case I would use 3 gunicorn worker. Since `(2 x $num_cores) + 1` converts to 2x1+1=3 right?
Sorry for noobish question, just to be sure..

Comment: Yes, you should assume if the limit set to the CPU is less than 1000m then it would reside in single core only. Since you have 3 worker node with 1 core. In total each worker node will have 1000m CPU with them. So you would not be able to allocate any pod with more that 1000m limit. But,as you told you need only 200m limit, I guess you would be fine

Comment: @PrafullLadha, the documentation about cgroups can be complicated, but as far as I understand, it's not true that it will necessarily stick to one core if you set 200m. Remember that this is a measure of CPU time (in relation to a core), but not necessarily number of cores used.